# VBA Author and sending Date of .msg files on desktop folder

Tags: vba, outlook, msg

I am trying to write a macro that goes through 30k+ .msg files in a Desktop Folder and Subfolders. The goal is to get the Sending Date and Author if the File Name contains "Visa Process--" or "Document Signed--". In addition, this shall only be done for the earliest of the documents. So let's say we are in a subfolder and there are 3 files that relate to "Visa Process--", then only the earliest shall be considered.

Getting the Sending Dates is what I managed so far but I do not know how to implement getting the Author. I activated the Outlook Add-In but I am new to VBA and sample codes from the internet did not help me with my limited knowledge.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately, I do not know how to provide you with a sample file here but I will gladly send it via Email.

Here my (working code) for the Sending Dates of both Email Types:

```
'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FSO As Object, fld As Object, Fil As Object
Dim fsoFile As Object
Dim fsoFol As Object
Dim fsoSubFol As Object
Dim folderPath As String, subfolderPath As String, folderName As String, FilePath As String
Dim StepOne As String, StepTwo As String, FileName As String, CompareDate As String
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim FindExistingEntry As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Feuil2")


With ws
    .UsedRange.Clear
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Main Folder:"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "File Name:"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "MSG Date:"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "File Name:"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Approved Date:"
    .Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then MsgBox "No folder selected! Exiting script.": Exit Sub
    folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
If FSO.FolderExists(fld) Then
    For Each fsoFol In FSO.GetFolder(folderPath).SubFolders

On Error Resume Next
            subfolderPath = fsoFol & "\Mails"

            For Each fsoSubFol In FSO.GetFolder(subfolderPath).Files


                FilePath = fsoSubFol
                FileName = Split(FilePath, "\")(4)        'Get only "Visa Process--2017-06-07 15h24m00s.MSG" of target file 4
                folderName = Split(FilePath, "\")(2)
                If Mid(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, ".") + 1) = "MSG" Then

                    'Example: Visa Process--2017-06-07 15h24m00s.MSG
                    If InStr(1, FileName, "Visa Process--", vbTextCompare) <> 0 And Left(FileName, 1) = "V" Then

                        NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

                        'Example: Visa Process--2017-06-07 15h24m00s.MSG
                        StepOne = Split(FileName, "--")(1)  'No "Visa Process--"
                        StepTwo = Mid(StepOne, 1, 10)       'No Time-Stamp

                        'Make sure to only include the earliest date for each Main Folder "MPCV....."
                        Set FindExistingEntry = ws.Range("A2:A4000").Find(folderName)

                        'If there is already an entry...
                        If Not FindExistingEntry Is Nothing Then
                            CompareDate = ws.Cells(FindExistingEntry.Row, 3).Value

                            'Replace old date for that Main Folder if new date is earlier than previous
                            If DateValue(CompareDate) > DateValue(StepTwo) Then

                                ws.Cells(FindExistingEntry.Row, 2).Value = FileName
                                ws.Cells(FindExistingEntry.Row, 3).Value = DateValue(CompareDate)

                            'Do nothing if Main Folder date is later
                            ElseIf DateValue(CompareDate) < DateValue(StepTwo) Then

                            End If
                        'If there is no entry for the same Main Folder, simply add a new line
                        ElseIf FindExistingEntry Is Nothing Then

                            ws.Cells(NextRow + 1, 1).Value = folderName
                            ws.Cells(NextRow + 1, 2).Value = FileName
                            ws.Cells(NextRow + 1, 3).Value = DateValue(StepTwo)

                        End If

                    End If

                    'Do the same for the second document
                    If InStr(1, FileName, "Document signed--", vbTextCompare) <> 0 And Left(FileName, 1) = "D" Then

                        NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

                        'Example: Document signed--2017-06-07 15h24m00s.MSG
                        StepOne = Split(FileName, "--")(1)  'No "Document signed--"
                        StepTwo = Mid(StepOne, 1, 10)       'No Time-Stamp

                        'Make sure to only include the earliest date for each Main Folder "MPCV....."
                        Set FindExistingEntry = ws.Range("A2:A4000").Find(folderName)

                        'If there is already an entry...
                        If Not FindExistingEntry Is Nothing Then
                            CompareDate = ws.Cells(FindExistingEntry.Row, 3).Value

                            'Replace old date for that Main Folder if new date is earlier than previous
                            If DateValue(CompareDate) > DateValue(StepTwo) Then

                                ws.Cells(FindExistingEntry.Row, 4).Value = FileName
                                ws.Cells(FindExistingEntry.Row, 5).Value = DateValue(CompareDate)

                            'Do nothing if Main Folder date is later
                            ElseIf DateValue(CompareDate) < DateValue(StepTwo) Then

                            End If
                        'If there is no entry for the same Main Folder, simply add a new line
                        ElseIf FindExistingEntry Is Nothing Then

                            'ws.Cells(NextRow + 1, 1).Value = folderName
                            'ws.Cells(NextRow, 4).Value = Filename
                            'ws.Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = DateValue(StepTwo)

                        End If

                    End If
                End If
            Next
    Next
End If

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Scan Complete!"

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object (before entering the loop), retrieve the Namespace object from `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`, and use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` passing the file na of the MSG file. The retrieved MailItem object will contain properties like `Subject`, `SenderName`, `SenderEmailAddress`, `SentOn`, etc.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, thank you very much for your response. I will try to implement your suggestion! Let me get back to you in a few minutes

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. It worked after a bit of adjusting. Do you maybe have any ideas on how to make it faster? Feel free to edit the code above.